# AccessToken for Google Cloud Print

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have same situation like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851544/access-token-for-google-cloud-print-service/16676621#16676621). I'm a printer owner. I need print pdf from web-site on my printer without oAuth2. And I undestand that I must set my access token instead use oAuth2, but I don't undestand how can I get my accessToken without expire time.
Has anybody decision same problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [access token for google cloud print service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851544/access-token-for-google-cloud-print-service)